# Sorting DBList using Collections.sort

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, collections

I have a `DBList` that contains `DBObjects` from a `cursor = coll.find()` query. I have a field named `timestamp` inside each `DBObject` and I want to sort the `DBList` by  **latest timestamp** . I know I can use `Collections.sort()` here but being new to mongoDB's java API, I can't seem to be able to sort based on a specific field. I would really appreciate the help.

The `unsorted list` was formed using this :

```
      DBCursor cursor = coll.find(whereQuery);                  

      while(cursor.hasNext()) {
          DBObject o = cursor.next();
          System.out.println(o.toString());
          unsortedList.add(o);

      }
```

After this, I want to sort `unsortedList` in the descending order of `timestamp`. I'm quite unclear on how to do this and thanks in advance for the help.

Also solutions, such as `coll.find().sort(timestamp,-1)` can't be used because there is an outer `for` loop which keeps changing the `whereQuery`. The `list` must be sorted only  *after*  the query is done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that how do you change your query. Could you show me the code that you change your query in the for loop, I think i can provide a better query for you.
MongoDB can support very complicated queries.

Strill, I think a better way is letting mongoDB sort it for you.
You can write like:

```
coll.find(whereQueryModified).sort(new BasicDBObject("timestamp",-1));
```

If you cannot use the sort method, you might need to use a newer version of mongoDB driver.

Besides, "timestamp" is to long for a key of an object. It's very space exhausting for mongoDB because mongoDB store every key and value in disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the query as following strategy:

```
List<DBObject> pipeline=new ArrayList<DBObject>();
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("date", sdf.format(new Date())).append("country", country));
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$details");
DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("details.datetime", -1));
DBObject limit = new BasicDBObject("$limit", 1);

pipeline.add(match);
pipeline.add(unwind);
pipeline.add(sort);
pipeline.add(limit);

AggregationOutput outputoutput = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `DBList` implements [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

`Collections.sort(unsortedList, Comparator.comparing(DBObject::getTimestamp).reversed());`